# want to receive json data sent via ajax using php and store it in db

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

following is my js

```
            var obj = {};
            obj["name"] = uname;
            obj["repo"] = repo;
            obj["length"] = linelength;
            var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "example.php",
                data: {'data' : json},
                success: function(response){
                    console.log("success");
                }
            });
```

and following is my php

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST["data"])){
    $myData = $_POST["data"];
    $ddata = json_decode($myData);
    $name = $ddata->name;
    $repo = $ddata->repo;
    $length = $ddata->length;
    $query = "INSERT INTO user('name', 'repo', 'length') VALUES($name, $repo, $length)";
    $db->exec($query);
}   ?>
```

The log is showing success but the data are not getting added in db. Your help will be appreciated

Comment: You probably need quotes in your query `VALUES('$name', '$repo', '$length')`

Comment: What errors you are getting ..?

Comment: change `INSERT INTO user(name, repo, length) VALUES('$name', '$repo', '$length')`

Answer (score 0):

Column names should be enclosed (if at all) with backticks `` ` `` and values enclosed in single quotes `'`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user (`name`, `repo`, `length`)
          VALUES ('$name', '$repo', '$length')";
```

However, I would say that your code is vulnerable to injection and you should use placeholders - switch to using prepared statements!

Comment: I am able to add data using get method but I don't know how to do it with post method. Thanks for the reply but adding the data into database is not an issue. But receiving json encoded data from ajax and accessing it in php is the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

remove `'` on your columns names and put inputs in 2 `'` :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user(name, repo, length) VALUES('$name', '$repo', '$length')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user(name,repo,length) VALUES('".$name."','".$repo."','".$length."')";
```

Comment: FYI: This is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.